# How to bind a List<T1> or List<T2> to a UserControl.List<IInterfaceForT1AndT2>?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have an Interface and two classes.

```
public interface IFieldValue
{
  Int64 FieldId { get; set; }
  string Value { get; set; }
}

public class CarFieldValue : IFieldValue
{
  public Int64 CarId { get; set; }
  public Int64 FieldId { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; } 
}

public class HouseFieldValue : IFieldValue
{
  public Int64 HouseId { get; set; }
  public Int64 FieldId { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; } 
}
```

Now I have a generic usercontrol for displaying the field values of either `Car` or `House`. The usercontrol is bound to the according ViewModel.

```
public class CarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  (...)

  private ObservableCollection<CarFieldValue> _FieldValues;
  public ObservableCollection<CarFieldValue> FieldValues
  {
    get { return _FieldValues; }
    set
    {
      if (_FieldValues!= value)
      {
        _FieldValues= value;
        SendPropertyChanged("FieldValues");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
public class HouseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  (...)

  private ObservableCollection<HouseFieldValue> _FieldValues;
  public ObservableCollection<HouseFieldValue> FieldValues
  {
    get { return _FieldValues; }
    set
    {
      if (_FieldValues!= value)
      {
        _FieldValues= value;
        SendPropertyChanged("FieldValues");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The usercontrol part looks like this:

```
public IReadOnlyList<IFieldValues> FieldValues
{
  get { return (IReadOnlyList<IFieldValues>)GetValue(FieldValuesProperty); }
  set { SetValue(FieldValuesProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldValuesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FieldValues", typeof(IReadOnlyList<IFieldValues>), typeof(FieldValuesControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

The binding takes place in XAML in the Views, e.g. in the CarView:

```
<myCtrls:FieldValuesControl FieldValues="{Binding MyCarViewModel.FieldValues}" />
```

I found that solution here][1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35851257/523854) and it works so far. But I need to edit (add or remove) items in the usercontrol.
When I use an `IList<IFieldValues>` instead of `IReadOnlyList<IFieldValues>` the binding doesn't work. There are no binding errors/warnings.

I also tried `ICollection<IFieldValues>` without success.
I could use `IEnumerable<IFieldValues>` as suggested in the comments but then I can't `Add()` items because I can't cast the `IEnumerable`.

How can I implement this scenario?

**Update**
Since I didn't find a better solution I use `ObservableCollection<IFieldValues>` on both the ViewModels and the usercontrol. As my ViewModels doesn't do much with the Lists it's not to complicated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - have you tried specifying a OneWay binding?

Comment: @LordWilmore OneWay doesn't help.

Comment: @Clemens: Yes, `IEnumerable<IFieldValues> does work, but I need to add/remove items in the usercontrol. I can`t cast the `IEnumerable` there to a `List` or `ObservableCollection`. Sorry, going to make that more clear in the question.

Comment: If you need to add items in the user control, you can't operate on a specialized list. However, you can hold a copy of the list items in a separate list of matching type. Something like `List<IFieldValues> items = srcList.Cast<IFieldValues>().ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a `ObservableCollection` or an `IEnumerable` in your `UserControl`?

Like other do:

- [how to bind collection to custom control in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415097/how-to-bind-collection-to-custom-control-in-wpf)
- [wpf binding collection property in UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321710/wpf-binding-collection-property-in-usercontrol)

And I think your problem is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446633/binding-a-collection-to-a-custom-control-property)

> Problem is in your `DependencyProperty` registration. `Co-variance is not applicable for generic lists`

Another possibility would be to use the `ItemCollection` class. The same is used from the default `ItemsControl` (see [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,0f1d402ffb659783)).

Comment: Using an `ObservableCollection` leeds to binding errors because you can 't bind an explicit `ObservableCollection<CarFieldValues>` respectively `ObservableCollection<HouseFieldValues>` to an generic `ObservableCollection<IFieldValues>`.
`IEnumerable` and `IList` don't work too. Only `IReadOnlyList`. I haven't figured out the difference yet.

Comment: @gumo Have you tried `ObservableCollection<object>`?

Comment: Using `object` has the same binding error as `ObservableCollection<XxxFieldValues>` "System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'ObservableCollection`1[CarFieldValue]' and 'ObservableCollection`1[Object]'. Consider using Converter property of Binding..."

Comment: @gumo the idea behind using means that the `ObservableCollection` from the `ViewModels` uses `object` too

Comment: Ah, OK, now I understand. I would like to avoid the then neccessary casting from object to `IFieldValues`.
I will try `ItemCollection`.